# Google Maps Directions API using REST with Groovy

Tags: api, rest, groovy

```
@Grab('com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.2')
import wslite.rest.*

String key = 'my-key'
def client = new RESTClient('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/')
def response = client.get(path: 'xml',
query: [
    origin: 'Disneyland',
    destination: 'Universal Studios Hollywood',
    sensor: 'false',
    mode: 'driving',
    key: 'my-key'
    ])

println response.DirectionsResponse.status
println response.DirectionsResponse.summary
```

I'm trying to use the Google API directions using REST with Groovy but I can't seem to print from response.DirectionsResponse. It would either output null or an error. Am I missing something? I tried searching everywhere for an answer but I can't find one.

Answer (score 1):

Think you have 4 problems;

1. You need to pass `accept: ContentType.XML` to the get query
2. You need to use `response.xml` to get the parsed XML content of the response
3. You don't need `DirectionsResponse` as this is the root element of the document (pointed to already by `response.xml`)
4. `summary` is inside a node `route`

The following should work:

```
@Grab('com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.2')
import wslite.rest.*

def client = new RESTClient("https://maps.googleapis.com/")
def response = client.get(
    path: "/maps/api/directions/xml",
    accept: ContentType.XML,
    query: [
        origin: 'Disneyland',
        destination: 'Universal Studios Hollywood',
        sensor: 'false',
        mode: 'driving',
        key: 'AIzaSyBioD99qXv43yHLb9EuxemPeMHA1drpiqw'
    ])

println response.xml.status
println response.xml.route.summary
```

PS:  You probably want to generate a new key, as you've made that one public now, so many people could be using your allowance (if you're on the free tier), or your money (if you've paid for it)